# vim: comment/uncomment all lines in file containing a string

Tags: vim, vi

I have a big `python` file as follows:

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def foo():
    //function body

@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def foobar():
    //function body
.
.
.
```

Like this there are many functions in the file. I want to comment all the lines which contains the pattern `login_required` or `user_passes_test`. How to comment those lines?

I use [tComment](https://github.com/vim-scripts/tComment) plugin. So I can toggle line comment using `gcc` key-mapping. Can it be used?

There are also other files in the project which contains similar functions. So how can I comment these lines in all files in the project?

And again if I need to **uncomment** those lines how do I?

Comment: Have you considered regular expressions for your solution? Something like :%s/^login_required/^@login_required/g

Comment: Ok. I got a regular expression `:g/pattern/s/^/;` by which i am able to comment those lines. But how to uncomment them?

Comment: how about looking for "// pattern"? or \/\/ pattern using \ as escape char) and changinng back to "pattern"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:global/{pat}/{cmd}` command will run a command, `{cmd}`, on every line matching pattern, `{pat}`. You can execute your tComment command via the `:normal` command. All together it looks like this:

```
:g/@login_required/norm gcc
```

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :norm
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to comment certain lines, then uncomment those same lines later, I'd use some kind of "marker" in the comment to make the job easier.

So to comment, for example:

```
1,$s/^\(.*@login_require\)/#FOO \1/
```

Then to uncomment:

```
1,$s/^#FOO //
```

You would choose `#FOO` so as not to be using it anywhere else for another purpose. You can even pick something simpler like `##`... really anything that starts with `#` that you're not already using.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be with VIM, but i think easier way to comment out in all project,multiple files:

```
sed -i 's/@login_required/#login_required/g' *
```

or for files in directories:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/@login_required/#login_required/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment lines containing `string`:

```
:%s/\(.*string\)/# \1/c
```

- `%s` - global substitute
- `\(.*string\)` - pattern to match
- `# \1` - replacement, `\1` is for the matched pattern
- `c` - confirm before substitution

Similarly, to uncomment:

```
:%s/# \(.*string\)/\1/c
```